# Upload a file to a public server using curl without using any authentication method

Tags: windows, curl

I am trying to upload a file to a server using below format and using curl:

```
curl -X PUT -T myFile.zip username@server:/path/to/main/folder
```

but i get the following error:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not familiar with the API you are executing to, but i'm pretty sure this is not the correct syntax.

to authenticate using username and password, you can use the `--user user@pass`

`curl -X PUT -u username:password http://example.com`

or even try something like this :

```
curl http://username:password@someapi.com/bla/bla?bla
```

Comment: This is a public fileserver location, no need to specify password. IT admin only provide me the username, the server, and the path within the server to push files, e.g. username@server:/path/to/main/folder so how to indicate this in curl? or curl is not supporting such format?

Comment: curl does not support this syntax generally. you should execute a curl command to an REST API endpoint, not to a filesystem.